# Photoshop: Batch Replace Smart Objects - Perspective Problem (Script by JJMack)

Tags: photoshop

I want to use the script by JJMack to create art mockups in photoshop.
The problem is that the photos do not change their perspective to fit in the frame.
For example, one frame stands sideways against the wall, but the photo was just put straight over the frame after running the script.

Can someone help?

I cant post the script, its too long.

I tried already to change the pixels of the photo but still its not working.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I appreciated that you can't post the script, but without even a link to the script in question you're not helping yourself.

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you add some screenshots or photos to clarify what you're talking about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So without seeing either the Photoshop document or the script code, it's hard to say what the problem or fix is.

First, I'd troubleshoot by ensuring that the Smart Object *itself* has the proper perspective / warp applied to it, to trigger the desired appearance? You can consult [this official Adobe guide on Smart Objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html) to make sure you're following all best practices. If the perspective warp is indeed in place, and it works when you replace the Smart Object contents manually, but it *doesn't* get applied via the script, there's probably some issue in how the script code is written.

If you're just looking for a simple fix, I would note that the [Batch-Replace Smart Objects plugin](https://exchange.adobe.com/apps/cc/8e3097ba/batch-replace-smart-objects) works for me just fine on Photoshop documents that have perspective warped Smart Objects. If you're just looking for an effective solution, which can automate this for you, and you want to have the replacement work properly on angled Smart Objects, you could just use that plugin.

Otherwise, without being able to actually see the script code, and test it out, it's hard to identify the specific problem with the script code. If you post the .jsx script code, we'd have a better chance of potentially helping you out.